# stuck with geany on linux

Tags: c++, linux, class, geany

So i started using geany with my linux distro but i'm having some trouble with it...

I'm trying to create a header file for a class and link it in a cpp file but it won't find my header file...

for demonstration:

***MyClass.hpp***

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP

class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass();
};

#endif
```

***MyClass.cpp***

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
```

the error i get is :

> MyClass.cpp:1:23: fatal error: MyClass.hpp: No such file or directory

any thoughts why that is? :S

Comment: Are both files on the same directory? Is the casing accurate? (Linux is case-sensitive on file names, not like Windows -by default-).

Comment: yes, they are on the same dir and the casing matches the actual name so nothing here :(

Comment: Strange... Can you please run *ls -l* on the directory where *MyClass.cpp* resides?

Comment: sure, im on windows right now but when i log into linux again ill post it :)

Comment: gannash@gannash-Inspiron-N5110:~/Desktop/Test$ ls 
main.cpp  main.o  MyClass.cpp  MyClass.hpp  MyClass.hpp.gch  MyClass.o

Comment: Can you post *main.cpp*?

Answer (score 0):

How did you compile it?
May be try

```
gcc *.cpp -I.
```

Comment: i used g++ not gcc - g++ -Wall -c filename, g++ -Wall -o filename

Comment: @ /tmp/1 $ cat MyClass.cpp 
#include "MyClass.hpp"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
@ /tmp/1 $ cat MyClass.hpp 
#ifndef MYCLASS_HPP
#define MYCLASS_HPP

class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass();
};

#endif

@ /tmp/1 $ g++ -Wall main.cpp MyClass.cpp

Comment: It must compile. check file names registry

Comment: still not working :( ive tryed it again and it printed this error: main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass()' when i tryed to create an instance of MyClass in the main function

Comment: oh im stupid i should have included the .cpp file and not the .hpp file like i used to in visual studio :S